# Copiar vários registros para a mesma tabela com alteração de valores

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO tags group_tags, title, active
SELECT group_tags, title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2;
```

---

**Primeiro**

Como executar está query para cada registro da tabela que contenha `group_tags = 2`?

---

**Segundo**

Para cada novo registro, como definir o valor da `group_tags` para `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tags (group_tags, title, active)
SELECT 1 as 'group_tags', title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2;
```

Execute apenas a segunda linha e veja se é o resultado esperado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tags (group_tags, title, active)
SELECT 1, title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

oi,

veja assim

```
INSERT INTO tags (1, title, active)
SELECT title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2;
```

Comment: Por que o `1` entrou como nome de coluna no `INSERT`?

Comment: Ta certo, comida de bola minha

Answer (score -1):

Experimente da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO tags(group_tags, title, active)
    with cte as (
        SELECT group_tags, title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2
    )
    SELECT  1, title, active FROM cte
```

A primeira parte

```
with cte as (
     SELECT group_tags, title, active FROM tags WHERE group_tags = 2
)
```

Cria um contexto diferente, como sendo outra consulta SQL.

```
SELECT  1, title, active FROM cte
```

Fará as alterações necessárias antes de inserir.